# captureing output of nodejs via PHP exec

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, node.js, exec

I am trying to get the output from my node.js script via PHP exec thats wrapped inside an ajax call I am able to call it i think and get some feed back, but console.log doesn't seem to return to the output var

This is how i call the script

```
$ex = exec('/usr/local/bin/node '.$path.'doAjax.js >/dev/null/ 2>&1 &',$_POST,$out);
var_dump($ex,$out);
```

In doAjax.js i do

```
console.log('hhhhhhhhhhhhh');
```

But all i get for output is

```
string(0) "" array(0) { }
```

Is there another way todo output or capture it ?

Comment: The second argument to `exec()` should be a variable that receives an array of lines of output from the process and the third argument is a variable that receives the exit code of the process. So as your code is currently, `$_POST` should have the output lines appended to it. Did you try dumping `$_POST`?

Answer (score 0):

yes the code and output where switched, but then i always got code 8

i semi solved this problem by moving code to the httpd doc root and changing to shell_exec

though i still need to make sure apache won't be able to display the node code